# How do stained bedclothes affect the nightly price?

Tags: hotels

I stayed at a [Hilton Garden Inn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chained-brand_hotels) in Canada for 1 night at $150 CAD pre-tax. Shortly after my late arrival around 23:00 local time, I spotted some small red (not sure if this were blood) and orange stains on the [bedclothes](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bedclothes), which I reported  to the front desk. The receptionist said that as the only person at the hotel postmidnight, she couldn't do anything, but would note my complaint. So I placed towels to cover the stains on the linen, and slept without the [duvet](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/duvet).

The next day, nobody contacted me. I then stumbled on the Housekeeping Manager in the hallway, who amply apologized and offered a 15% discount after seeing the stains in my room.

Yet I'm uncertain how much discount is warranted? 15% feels too meager to me: is it?

Comment: You should call or e-mail the corporate customer service line with your complaint. Most hotels are franchises (and some are even operated by a third company under contract to the actual franchise owners) but headquarters has an interest in maintaining their brand.

Comment: This is purely a matter of personal opinion, sorry.

Comment: Also, what's with the random links? Why do you think we need a link to Wikipedia's list of chain hotels, and dictionary definitions of two completely normal words?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each company will be willing to offer different amounts and discounts depending on the situation, others will simply move you rooms. If the housekeeping manager has offered 15% that is probably what they offer as standard. Contact the company themselves, either online or by phone and explain the situation. If there is more discount to be had, they will be the ones to offer it (especially since the local hotels may not have the power to do this).

Customer support phone numbers and emails can be found [here.](https://www.hilton.com/en/hi/customersupport/index.jhtml)